# I'm trying to create a superclass that can return an instance of itself with its initial conditions and pass that functionality on to subclasses

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, arguments, spread-syntax

**I found a solution while typing out this question, I will still post the question, since I couldn't find anything on this, if that isn't appreciated, I will remove this on request.**

I've done it for a class that doesn't have subclasses like so:

```
export class SomeClass{
    constructor(a, b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.args = arguments;
    }

    getDefault(){
        return new SomeClass(...this.args);
    }
};
```

This works satisfactorily for now. I'm aware that when passing a shallow copy of an object to the constructor, `getDefault()` will be unable to recreate the initial values of that object's properties. That's an issue to be sorted out later (or might never actually be an issue).

Now I would love to inherit from this class and have all subclasses mirror this ability - but it appears to me that the superclass would need to be aware of any parameters a subclass might take, which somewhat defeats the purpose of using inheritance in the first place.

Solution:

```
export class SuperClass{
    constructor(a, b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.args = arguments;
    }

    getDefault(){
        return new this.constructor(...this.args);
    }
};

export class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    constructor(a, b, c){
        super(...arguments);
        this.c = c;
    }
};
```

It should be noted that this passes a bunch of parameters the superclass doesn't know what to do with, which I'm unsure about how *dirty* this is considered in JavaScript. Also, this works because `this` refers to the instance `getDefault()` is called on, so `this.constructor` calls the constructor of the subclass with the parameters previously stored when `super(...arguments)` was called. I do not know how good of a solution this is.

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer and accept it if it answers what you were asking.